# Go to Event or SelectMethod definition from markup

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, hotkeys

Similar to <kbd>F12</kbd> hotkey from code, I would like to go to the method that is used in the markup, eg.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsADDOCs" runat="server" SelectMethod="DataSet_SelectForProject"
    TypeName="DataLogic.tADDOCList" OnSelecting="dsADDOCs_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="iORDRID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="iAccesses" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="iTracer" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue="" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

So here if I would <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> on `dsADDOCs_Selecting`, than it would go to the codebehind to the `dsADDOCs_Selecting` method, or when I do the same on `DataSet_SelectForProject`, than it would open `DataSet_SelectForProject` method in `DataLogic.tADDOCList`

Is there an option, plugin or anything to do this? It would be really helpful.